# Is there a way to tell user the multi-sort order in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-multisortable

I am using jqgrid(4.5.4) and implemented multi-sorting in it using code below.

```
multiSort: true
```

The client also wants to see what column they sorted first and so on. Do we have a way to display it in jqgrid? If this feature doesn't exist, we request this in future release. Thanks

My suggestion is

To show the list of column-name, sort-icon and a close button next to it in the form of **tags** similar to stack overflow tags(this would be great).Just plain list is also fine. It can be displayed on top/below the grid. It should keep updating each time the sort is performed. We can remove sort on particular column by deleting the tag or clicking on column header(default behavior). The multi-sort order should still be preserved.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and which fork  ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old version of jqGrid in version <= 4.7)? What you mean under "I am ... implemented multi-sorting"? Do you mean that you use `multiSort: true` option of jqGrid? How exactly you want to display the order of sorting? Do you have an suggestion?

Comment: @Oleg : Thanks for your quick reply. I have updated my question with necessary details you asked for. Thanks :)